# Filter rows by whether a text column contains any words in a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Server database table has a column `text` which is a long string of text.

The search list is a string of words separated by comma. I want to grab those rows where the text column contains any one of words in the string.

```
DECLARE @words_to_search nvarchar(50)
SET @words_to_search = 'apple, pear, orange' 

SELECT * 
FROM myTbl
WHERE text ??? --how to specify text contains @words_to_search
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: perhaps look at using full text search or elasticsearch or lucene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to convert the words to search into a single column table, and then `JOIN` that to your table using `LIKE`:

```
DECLARE @words_to_search nvarchar(50)
SET @words_to_search = 'apple,pear,orange'

SELECT *
FROM myTbl
JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@words_to_search, ',') ON text LIKE '%' + value + '%';
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66771/2)

Note that as the query is written it will (for example) match `apple` within `Snapple`. You can work around that by making the `JOIN` condition a bit more complex:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTbl t
JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@words_to_search, ',') v
  ON t.text LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]' + value + '[^A-Za-z]%'
  OR t.text LIKE value + '[^A-Za-z]%'
  OR t.text LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]' + value;
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db740/4)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I want!  super thanks!

Comment: @zesla only thing to be aware of is that as it's currently written it will match words inside others; you may want to change the `JOIN` condition to something more sophisticated as in this example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db740/4. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use `exists`, unless you want to return the matching word.

Second, you can do this with a single `like` comparison  If words are separated by spaces:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from string_split(@words_to_search, ',') s
              where ' ' + t.text + ' ' like '% ' + value + ' %'
             );
```

For more generic separators, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from string_split(@words_to_search, ',') s
              where ' ' + t.text + ' ' like '%[^A-Za-z]' + value + '[^A-Za-z]%'
             );
```

Or whatever describes your separators.

Note that your list of words is separated by a comma-space, not just a comma.  However, based on your *description* (not the sample data), I have only used a `','` for the separator.